# Gorm change column length

Tags: database, sqlite, go, orm, go-gorm

I currently have a table for the following struct:

```golang
type Action struct {
    ID            uint   `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id"`
    ActionType    string `json:"action_type"`
    ChangedColumn string `json:"changed_column"`
    NewValue      string `json:"new_value"`
}
```

By default, GORM has created the `NewValue` column as `VARCHAR(255)` however I need that to be longer and from reading their migrations documentation, I can't figure out just how to do that. I added `gorm:"size:4095"` to `NewValue` and added the migration, `tx.AutoMigrate(&models.Action{})` but the column remains `VARCHAR(255)`.

How do I change the column length from `VARCHAR(255)` to `VARCHAR(4095)`?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that you cannot alter columns in SQLite. My workaround was to rename the table, create a new one with the modified length, and insert the data over.

```golang
tx.Model(&models.Action{}).Exec("ALTER TABLE actions RENAME TO actions_old")
tx.AutoMigrate(&models.Action{})
tx.Model(&models.Action{}).Exec("INSERT INTO actions SELECT * FROM actions_old")
```